# How to append text to a specific place in a file using Phing

Tags: php, phing

I am trying to append text to a specific place in a file using Phing.

Using Phing's default `<append>` places text at the end of a file, I have also tried using `<filterchain>` but it does not support the `<append>` parameter.

Example:

I need to append the text `Hello World` between line2 and line3.

```
//config.php

line1

line2

line3
```

Code which appends text after line3

```
<append destFile="\config.php" 
        text="${line.separator} Hello World; ${line.separator}" />
```

Is there a better built in solution to accomplish this besides removing `line2` using `replace` and re-adding it as `line2 ${line.separator} Hello World` ?

ps. I cannot use a placeholder or token since the file is downloaded from a  remote source and cannot be changed.

Comment: you could add a placeholder like `//{{PLACEHOLDER}}` which you can replace instead.

Comment: I should have added I cannot use a placeholder since this file is downloaded from a remote source..will add it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only solution I came up with was to replace the existing text before where you want to include data and then just add it back.

For example:

```
 <reflexive file="\config.php">
    <filterchain>
       <replaceregexp>
        <regexp pattern="line2" replace="line2 ${line.separator} Hello World" />
       </replaceregexp>
    </filterchain>
 </reflexive>
```